# Make lsblk list devices by-id

Tags: linux, lsblk

I'm constantly having the situation where I want to correlate the output of `lsblk` which prints devices in a tree with their name in the scheme of `/dev/sdXY` with the drives `/dev/disk/by-id/` names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The by-id names consists of the drive model together with the serial something which `lsblk` can be instructed to list:

```
lsblk -o name,model,serial
```

The output of this command will look something like this:

```
NAME   MODEL            SERIAL
sda    SAMSUNG HD203WI  S1UYJ1VZ500792                                       
├─sda1                  
└─sda9                  
sdb    ST500DM002-1BD14 W2APGFP8
├─sdb1                  
└─sdb9                  
sdc    ST500DM002-1BD14 W2APGFS0
├─sdc1                  
└─sdc9
```

For posterity here's also a longer command with some commonly used columns:

```
sudo lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,model,serial,mountpoint
```

The output of which could be:

```
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE            LABEL         MODEL            SERIAL          MOUNTPOINT
sda      1,8T zfs_member                      SAMSUNG HD203WI  S1UYJ1VZ500792
├─sda1   1,8T zfs_member        storage                                        /home    
└─sda9     8M zfs_member                                                       
sdb    465,8G btrfs                           ST500DM002-1BD14 W2APGFP8        
├─sdb1 465,8G btrfs                                                            
└─sdb9     8M btrfs                                                            
sdc    465,8G btrfs                           ST500DM002-1BD14 W2APGFS0        
├─sdc1 465,8G btrfs             rpool                                          /      
└─sdc9     8M btrfs
```

Comment: Unfortunately, on my current opensuse and ubuntu systems, `lsblk -o serial` did not output anything.   
Furtheron, the output of `lsblk -o model` did not exacty match that in `/dev/disk/by-id/`.

Comment: I can't believe I've been relying on `df` for so long. I need to start leveraging `lsblk` with these extra options. It would make me a lot less paranoid when doing destructive operations like `dd`, `rsync --delete`, `mkfs`, `sgdisk` etc. etc.

Answer (score 7):

As found [here](https://medium.com/@DazWilkin/compute-engine-identifying-your-devices-aeae6c01a4d7), the device ids can be seen by `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id`.
So, Your task could be accomplished e.g. by something like:

```
lsblk |awk 'NR==1{print $0" DEVICE-ID(S)"}NR>1{dev=$1;gsub("[^[:alnum:]]","",dev);printf $0"\t\t";system("find /dev/disk/by-id -lname \"*"dev"\" -printf \" %p\"");print "";}'
```

or

```
lsblk -r|awk 'NR==1{print $0" DEVICE-ID(S)"}NR>1{dev=$1;printf $0" ";system("find /dev/disk/by-id -lname \"*"dev"\" -printf \" %p\"");print "";}'
```